# Target localhost from GCP Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am working with GCP Cloud Tasks API on localhost at the moment. I am able to enqueue tasks in Google from localhost by injecting my default credentials.

I am passing a localhost URL as the callback when the task is to execute. Is this possible to do for development?

Or does the callback URL have to be a hosted endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

See Cloud Tasks [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks):

*With this release of HTTP Targets, Cloud Tasks handlers can now be run on any HTTP endpoint with a **public IP address**, such as Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, GKE, Compute Engine, or even an on-prem web server. Your tasks can be executed on any of these services in a reliable, configurable fashion.*

Meaning, it's currently not possible to pass a localhost URL as a callback when executing tasks. For development purposes, Cloud Tasks doesn't have an official emulator yet but a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/185153027) already exists. Please make sure to ["star"](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) it so it can gain traction.

As an alternative to your objective, here's a few third-party Cloud Task emulators so you can test locally. Check out the following links:

- https://gitlab.com/potato-oss/google-cloud/gcloud-tasks-emulator
- https://github.com/aertje/cloud-tasks-emulator

Comment: Not possible to pass a localhost URL, but if you have a public IP on your workstation and you can reach  your local app from the internat, you can use this public IP to access to your local dev.

Comment: Note that Cloud task only perform a HTTP call. Do it manually to validate locally the action.